# mysql : why would I require AttributeConverter over enum to map a DB column having enum datatype as enum with a JPA entity?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a `user` database table as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_ name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `active_status` ENUM('ACTIVE', 'PENDING', 'DEACTIVATED', 'BLOCKED', 'SPAM', 'DELETED') NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_id_UNIQUE` (`unique_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I mapped it to a corresponding JPA entity class as:

```
@Entity
public class User implements OfloyEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int userId;

//other fields

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "active_status", nullable = false, length = 11)
private UserStatus activeStatus;
```

As you can see, I have mapped `activeStatus` to a `enum UserStatus` to restrict the entires from persistence layer itself.

```
public enum UserStatus {

    ACTIVE,
    PENDING,
    DEACTIVATED,
    BLOCKED,
    DELETED,
    SPAM
}
```

I want to know is there any drawback of using this approach for implementing a DB enum in persistence layer? I gone throw multiple articles which recommend using [AttributeConverter](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/) but since the the values in my enum are very limited and have less chances of modification, I am unable to relate all those articles with my requirement.

Is there something I am missing, or any improvement can be done in my design?

Articles I gone throw:
[vladmihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
[thorban](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/) and some other stackoverflow questions.

**Update**: After reading the answer from Jens, I decided to implement `AttributeConverter`(for user's `gender`). And that confused me a little:
**Why I decided to use enum as MYSQL column type** : as it restrict the values and require less space. Because MYSQL stores the ordinal value of it's enum behind the scene and when asked for the value it represents the String value of that, it saves space.
My implementation of gender:

```
public enum UserGender {

    MALE('M'),
    FEMALE('F'),
    OTHER('O');

    private Character shortName;

    private UserGender(Character shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public Character getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public static UserGender fromShortName(Character shortName) {
        switch (shortName) {
        case 'M': return UserGender.MALE;

        case 'F' : return UserGender.FEMALE;

        case 'O' : return UserGender.OTHER;

        default:
            throw new UserGenderNotSupportedException("user gender with shortName : " + shortName + " not supported");
        }

    }

}
```

converter class:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UserGenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<UserGender, Character> {

    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(UserGender userGender) {
        return userGender.getShortName();
    }

    @Override
    public UserGender convertToEntityAttribute(Character dbGender) {
        return UserGender.fromShortName(dbGender);
    }

}
```

**Now, the major doubts**:
1. As per blogs, using `MYSQL enum` is evil in DB, because someday if I need to add extra values to the enum column and that would require a table ALTER, but isn't it the same case with using `AttributeConverter`? Because there also we use a `java enum`, which would need to be change if someday new genders are required?
2. If I use `AttributeConverter`, I would have to document java `enum`(`UserGender` here) explaination somewhere so that DBA can understand what F,M,O stands for. Am I right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The articles gave you a rich selection of potential drawbacks:

Using `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` has the following:

- It uses lots of space compared to other options. Note that means more data needs to be loaded and transferred over the wire this has an effect on performance as well. We have no idea if this is a problem for you and you won't know either until you made some performance tests.
- Ties the name of the enum values hard to the column values. Which can be risky since developers are used to renaming stuff quickly and you would need tests with actual legacy data to catch this.

If you don't work with really huge amounts of data for which updating the column for all rows is an actual problem, I wouldn't sweat it. It's easy enough to introduce an `AttributeConverter` and update the data when the simple solution actually becomes a problem.

#### Update regarding the updated question:

1. I don't buy into the argument that anything is "evil" because it might require an `ALTER TABLE` statement. By this argument, we should abolish relational databases completely because using them requires DDL and evolution of an application will require more of it. Of course, the necessity of a DDL statement makes a deployment a little more complex. But you need to be able to handle this thing anyway.

   But it is true that with an `AttributeConverter` you wouldn't need any DDL in this case, because you'd just put another value in the same column which doesn't have any special constraints except the maximum length of the value. This assumes you don't have a check constraint on the column to limit the legal values.

   2. Do you have to document the relationship between `Enum` and the value stored in the DB? Depends on your team. Does the DBA even care about the meaning of the data? Does the DBA have access and the skills to understand the Java code? If the DBA needs or wants to know and can't or won't get the information from the source code you have to document it. True.

Comment: hello Jens, I have updated my question, could you please now solve my queries.